# Java application doesn't know name of file being opened - Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, file-association

I have a Java application in an application bundle that has a file association (using Info.plist) that runs when a document is double-clicked. How do I get the filename of the document that was double-clicked in my Java application? Right now my Java app just runs and displays an empty document. There doesn't seem to be any command line arguments passed to the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to implement [ApplicationListener](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Java/Reference/1.5.0/appledoc/api/com/apple/eawt/ApplicationListener.html) or extend [ApplicationAdapter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Java/Reference/1.5.0/appledoc/api/com/apple/eawt/ApplicationAdapter.html) and implement the handleOpenFile() method. See http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/01/05/swing.html for a more elaborate explanation.

Comment: Some additional links that helped me solve this

http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/java-handle-drag-drop-events-mac-osx-dock-application-icon

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Java/Reference/1.5.0/appledoc/api/index.html

http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=414409&forumID=316