# IOS Custom Icon Email Attachment

Tags: iphone, ios, email, cfbundleidentifier, mfmailcomposer

I registered my own custom CFBundleDocumentTypes filetype as described in this link: [How do I register a custom filetype in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186401/how-do-i-register-a-custom-filetype-in-ios)

Everything is working fine except when I send a mail via MFMailComposeViewController there is still this plain default attachment icon instead of my own. 
When I receive the mail my own icon is displayed. Is it possible to change the default MFMailComposeViewController-attachment icon when sending the mail?

Thanks for your help,
Martin

Comment: this is a long time ago, but did you find the answer?

Answer (score 1):

When you add the attachment are you specifying the mime type correctly for your custom filetype? Perhaps you need to explicitly convert your UTI to a MIME type and then specify that when using the MFMailComposeViewController method:

```
- (void)addAttachmentData:(NSData*)attachment mimeType:(NSString*)mimeType fileName:(NSString*)filename
```

**Converting UTI to MIME type**

```
NSString *filePath = ... // file path for your file of a custom type.
CFStringRef fileExtension = (__bridge CFStringRef)[filePath pathExtension];
CFStringRef UTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, NULL);
CFStringRef MIMEType = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(UTI, kUTTagClassMIMEType);
CFRelease(UTI);
NSString *MIMETypeString = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)MIMEType;
```

Make sure to add and import the following frameworks:

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
```

Code snippet source: [Damien DeVille](http://ddeville.me/2011/12/mime-to-UTI-cocoa/)