# register a custom file type in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, file-type

I'm working on iOS application in which i want XML file to be the main input for this application.I've started a search trip (mainly in stackoverflow)to find how can i receive XML files from the Email.

first I've found an alternative method which was registering URL format for my files and use it in the Email instead of the file attached and this method works good.

now I want to use the file itself (attached) I found that i need to register a custom file type in this application depend on this resources

1. [apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_declare/understand_utis_declare.html)
2. [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186401/how-do-i-register-a-custom-filetype-in-ios)
3. [stackoverflow question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application)

related to this I've edited the info.plist file with this code

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>XML File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.IT.parseXML.XML</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

and this part also

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.text</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>XML Document</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>public.xml</string>
        <key>UTTypeReferenceURL</key>
        <string>http://www.w3.org/TR/rec-xml</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>xml</string>
            </array>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>text/xml</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

what I expect is to be able to handle XML files from emails... but this doesn't happen, what I'm missing ??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured out the problem in my configuration 
it was on this line

```
<key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.IT.parseXML.XML</string>
    </array>
```

it should be

```
<key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>public.XML</string>
    </array>
```

as it is in the public identifier

Comment: Can you help me out, do you know how the same would go for RSS or HTML? For example if an RSS link is clicked in Safari, Feedly gets open. Any idea how that works?

Comment: @RavindranathAkila please help me - I have the same question.

Comment: @RavindranathAkila What is your problem ?