# How to support files with a dynamic type identifier but a specific extension?

Tags: ios, uti

I would like my app to support "Open In.." functionality for an existing file type.

This file type, however, does not have a UTI.

I ran **mdls** for it in Terminal with the following result:

```
kMDItemContentType             = "dyn.ah62d4rv4ge80c25t"

kMDItemContentTypeTree         = (
    "public.data",
    "public.item"
)
```

Given that info, I added to my plist:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>extension</string>
            </array>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Alternate</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
                <string>public.item</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

However, this seems to ignore the "extension" and enables "Open In.." for any data file.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define UTIs in your Info.plist. Make one up if this is for an extension of your own creation and put it under the "Exported Type UTIs". If it's for a known type of file but the UTI isn't well known, you can put it under the "Imported Type UTIs" section of your Info.plist. In either case, you can now reference this UTI in the Document types section.

Comment: That worked! I guess I didn't realize I could just make up my own UTI under "Imported Types". Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Cool; for those looking for further info: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4186585/45375) for an example of an exported UTI (key `UTExportedTypeDeclarations` in the `Info.plist` file) - note that while the linked post is for iOS, it equally applies to OS X.

Comment: I did this, but `mdls` still reports my file as having a dynamic type identifier, despite clearing the launch services database. Here's my [`info.plist`](https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/64602f3c5bddd3196c1c76840692e951). Any idea why the system isn't picking up my exported uti?