# Can an iOS custom document editor return a file to the opening application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidocumentinteraction

I understand how to create an iOS application that is either a viewer or an editor of a document type.  There are several good questions on how to do this:

- [How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application?lq=1)
- [How do I register a custom filetype in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186401/how-do-i-register-a-custom-filetype-in-ios?lq=1)

My Question is this:  Once the "editor" application has received the file and made modifications to it, how does the file get back to the original application that requested the file be opened?

Restated:  If application 'A' has a file that is edited by application 'Editor', then 'A' can use the UIDocumentInteractionController to open the file in 'Editor'.  If I understand correctly, this causes the file to be copied into the "Documents" directory in the sandbox of the application 'Editor'.  The application 'Editor' can then make modifications to that file.  Once the 'Editor' is done making changes to the file, how then does application 'A' see those changes?

Answer (score 0):

You could register your application as a document handler for any known file types.  Then the user would 'Open in (your application)' from within the 'Editor' application once they were done making changes.

It's not ideal but it's the best I've come up with so far.  I hope there's a better way.