# Associate custom file extension to my app

Tags: macos, info.plist, uti

I am trying to associate a customized file extension let's say .abc to an application that I'm working on, so that when I double click on a file with that specific extension, my app launches.

A .abc file is just an archive file (.zip renamed to .abc) gathering several .xml files. When I load one of those .abc file with my app, the archive is extracted and the .xml files are parsed so I can set some values to some variables in my code.

If I understand correctly, there are two parts to this.

- letting OS X know that .abc extension must be associated with my app
- handling the file in my app once it's launched

For now I'm having issues with the first part. I've already read some stack overflow posts dealing with this subject (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186401/how-do-i-register-a-custom-filetype-in-ios/4186585#4186585) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application/2781290#2781290)) but I can't understand how they come up with the content of the string value for the key `<LSItemContentTypes>` (I've tried abc but it doesn't work) and for the key `<UTTypeIdentifier>`.

So far, this is the code I've added to my info.plist file

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <array>
            <string>myicon.icns</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>My Custom Project File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>don't.know.what.to.put.here.abc</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>

<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string> <!--not sure about that value-->
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>My Custom Project File</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>don't.know.what.to.put.here.abc</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>abc</string>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>application/octet-stream</string> <!--not sure about that value-->
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Also, is `UTTypeConformsTo` public.data ok in my case ? Since the customized file extension represents a archive containing xml files ?

If anyone could help me with this :)

Thanks

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question :D

Comment: I thought editing it was the way to go !

Comment: It's easy to overlook an answer that's posted inside the question (IMHO).

Comment: Ok I just edited the original post again and wrote a new answer. Thanks for the tips :)

Comment: I have trouble with this too. What is the minimum amount of information that you have to provide? I am trying with only `CFBundleTypeName` and `LSHandlerRank` but it does not work.

Comment: I don't know if it's the minimum, but here's what I filled : 
In CFBundleDocumentTypes : CFBundleTypeIconFile, CFBundleTypeName, CFBundleTypeRole, LSHandlerRank, LSItemContentTypes and In UTExportedTypeDeclarations : UTTypeConformsTo, UTTypeDescription, UTTypeIdentifier, UTTypeIdentifier (public.filename-extension & public.mime-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, I just misread the documentation, since the key `CFBundleTypeIconFile` is a string and not an array of string (I got confused because I was following and iOS example using the key `CFBundleTypeIconFiles` which is an array)