# Why is my custom CSS filetype not displaying for selection with FilePick on iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, xamarin, file-type

I have followed this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4186585/2287576) and several others to try and create my CSS file type.

I also saw this [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1587/_index.html) even though I am using Visual Studio for Mac.

So I manually edited the Info.plist and added the following entries:

It has the following:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Cascade Style Sheet</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>co.uk.trucklesoft.ElderlyRota.css</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Cascade Style Sheet</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>co.uk.trucklesoft.ElderlyRota.css</string>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>css</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

In my app I am using the Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.FilePicker and it is set like this:

```
async private void InstallStyleButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var customFileType =
        new FilePickerFileType(new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
        {
            {DevicePlatform.iOS, new[] { "co.uk.trucklesoft.ElderlyRota.css" } },
            {DevicePlatform.macOS, new[] {"css"} }
        });

    var pickResult = await FilePicker.PickAsync(new PickOptions
    {
        FileTypes = customFileType,
        PickerTitle = "Select stylesheet to install"

    });

    if(pickResult != null)
    {
        // Build target path (don't use hardcoded path)
        string targetFile = Path.Combine(_pageModel.StylesPath, pickResult.FileName);

        // OK to install?
        if(!File.Exists(targetFile)) 
        {
            // Install
            File.Copy(pickResult.FullPath, targetFile);

            // Add it
            StylesPicker.ItemsSource.Add(pickResult.FileName);

            // Select it
            StylesPicker.SelectedItem = pickResult.FileName;
        }
        
    }
}
```

When I start the Debugger in Visual Studio and try to click my Install button and navigate to a folder on the iCloud where I have CSS files:

[image]

I have highlighted the 3 files that are css files. I can't select them. If I remove the iOS entry from my `FileTypePicker` object then I can pick them because nothing is being filtered out. And the macOS filter works anyway.

What am I doing wrong?

---

## Update

Visual Studio for Mac does not expose all of the properties in the Advanced tab:

[image]

So the others that were indicated I manually added.

Grateful for assistance.

---

## Update 2

I followed another [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8413525-universal-type-identifiers-tutorial-for-ios-importing-and-exporting-app-data) so now I have:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Cascade Style Sheet</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>co.uk.trucklesoft.ElderlyRota.CascadeStyleSheet</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Cascade Style Sheet</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>co.uk.trucklesoft.ElderlyInfirm.CascadeStyleSheet</string>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>public.filename-extension</key>
        <array/>
        <key>Item 0</key>
        <string>css</string>
        <key>Item 1</key>
        <string>CSS</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

But still nothing. Two days of searching now. I keep going.

---

## Update 3

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Cascade Style Sheet</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>co.uk.trucklesoft.ElderlyRota.css</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Cascade Style Sheet</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>co.uk.trucklesoft.ElderlyInfirm.css</string>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.text</string>
            <string>public.plain-text</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>css</string>
                <string>CSS</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I fixed some issues with the code. Now my picker is calling `co.uk.trucklesoft.ElderlyRota.css` as the file type. But still doesn't work in the simulator.

---

## I noticed in Visual Studio for Mac

Every time I reopen my iOS project the info list reverts to:

[image]

See? It keeps resetting two of those elements. I expect this is part of the problem. Bug?

It is not a bug. VS for Mac just shows those labels but internally has the correct terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of searching I came across a valuable article:

[Cascading Style Sheet (CSS) File Format](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000482.shtml#sign)

In that article is had details about the UTType:

[image]

The key information being:

- `public.css`
- `text/css`

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_declare/understand_utis_declare.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH204-SW1) it states:

> If your code relies on third-party UTI types that may not be present on the system, you should declare those UTIs as **imported** types in your bundle.

All I was doing was **exporting**. This is my final Info.plist content:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Cascade Style Sheet</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>co.uk.trucklesoft.ElderlyRota.css</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Cascade Style Sheet</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>co.uk.trucklesoft.ElderlyInfirm.css</string>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.css</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>css</string>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>text/css</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTImportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Cascade Style Sheet</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>public.css</string>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>text/css</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

In Visual Studio for Mac it looks like this in the Advanced tab:

[image]

I am not 100% sure if I still need to **export** the file type any more but I kept it in just incase. I know that **imported** file types will take precedence.

When I run my app now:

[image]

All the CSS files are available.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? It is further explanation of one of SO answers you posted as your starting point.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2781290/7778287

Comment: No. All these examples are different. Some arrays, some not.