# Open a Java Application by clicking on a file in Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, javafx, plist, file-association

I have already gone through the following links :
[Double click document file in Mac OS X to open Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575190/double-click-document-file-in-mac-os-x-to-open-java-application)

Also I have mentioned the following steps to resolve my problem :

Firstly, I modified my Info.plist to add the two keys :

- CFBundleDocumentTypes: Lets OS X know the type of documents that can be opened by the app
- UTExportedTypeDeclarations: Tells OS X about custom document type specific to this app, which in this case is .example files

I am using Java FX maven plugin to build the app which requires a deploy folder to place the customised icons and the plist file.I place the plist in this folder so that when it tries to build the app , it picks up the plist from this location and places it in the Contents folder of the app.

It does that , but when I run my app and try to open .qi extension files with my app , nothing happens.I click on the file , but it doesnt perform any action.

Please help me and let me know if I am missing out something.